# Lightning Communities complex layouts best practices

Tags: lightning-community

When implementing customer portal on communities, often the simple layouts are not sufficient since the height of components or the complexities of the layout exceed the capabilities of the out-of-the-box templates. There are multiple solutions to this:

- Use HTML elements in communities
- Use custom layouts
- Use LWC components

How should the three be used to obtain the best results?